# $(this).attr("id") not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

as the title says, I keep getting "undefined" when I try to get the id attribute of an element, basically what I want to do is replace an element with an input box when the value is "other".

Here is the code:

```
function showHideOther(obj) {
    var sel = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(ID);

    if (sel == 'other') {
        $(this).html("<input type='text' name='" + ID + "' id='" + ID + "' />");

    } else {
        $(this).css({
            'display': 'none'
        });
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
          <span class='left'><label for='race'>Race: </label></span>
          <span class='right'><select name='race' id='race' onchange='showHideOther(this);'>
            <option>Select one</option>
            <option>one</option>
            <option>two</option>
            <option>three</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
          </span>
```

It is probably something small that I am not noticing, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the way the function is called (i.e. as a simple call to a function variable), `this` is the global object (for which `window` is an alias in browsers). Use the `obj` parameter instead.

Also, creating a jQuery object and the using its `attr()` method for obtaining an element ID is inefficient and unnecessary. Just use the element's `id` property, which works in all browsers.

```
function showHideOther(obj){ 
    var sel = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value;
    var ID = obj.id;

    if (sel == 'other') { 
        $(obj).html("<input type='text' name='" + ID + "' id='" + ID + "' />");
    } else {
        $(obj).css({'display' : 'none'});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Change

```
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
```

to

```
var ID = $(obj).attr("id");
```

Also you can change it to use jQuery event handler:

```
$('#race').change(function() {
    var select = $(this);
    var id = select.attr('id');
    if(select.val() == 'other') {
        select.replaceWith("<input type='text' name='" + id + "' id='" + id + "' />");
    } else {
        select.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: If it's passed from the onchange="" attribute it will be a reference to HTMLElement, not a jQuery object

Answer (score 7):

your using `this` in a function, when you should be using the parameter.

You only use $(this) in callbacks... from selections like

```
$('a').click(function() {
   alert($(this).href);
})
```

In closing, the proper way (using your code example) would be to do this

`obj.attr('id');`

Comment: "this" will always refer to the object you are working ON. And it can be used anywhere. Of course, if you know what you are doing.

Comment: instead of `$(this).href`, you could just `this.href` and also `obj.id`... btw, `obj.attr('id');` should be `$(obj).attr('id');` based on OP...

Answer (score 3):

You could also write your entire function as a jQuery extension, so you could do something along the lines of `$('#element').showHideOther();

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.fn, {
        showHideOther: function() {
            $.each(this, function() {
                var Id = $(this).attr('id');
                alert(Id);

                ...

                return this;
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Not that it answers your question...  Just food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting `$(this)` to refer to?

Do you mean `sel.attr("id");` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `inline event handler` and do it completly unobtrusive, like

```
​$('​​​​#race').bind('change', function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      id    = $this[0].id;

  if(/^other$/.test($(this).val())){
      $this.replaceWith($('<input/>', {
          type: 'text',
          name:  id,
          id: id
      }));
  }
});​​​
```

Comment: It's much cleaner and maintainable

Comment: While this code may be 'cleaner and maintainable', it doesn't answer the OP in an explantory way.

Comment: Whether the "unobtrusive" version is cleaner and more maintainable or not depends on the size of the application and, to an extent, personal taste. As an approach, it has significant downsides. For example, if a user makes a selection from the list before the document has finished loading, the event handler will not have been unobtrusively added and will not be called.

Comment: @Tim Down: You can't believe that for real. If you have such kind of worries just load the external `js code` in your document `head`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm not referring to loading the JavaScript. The usual technique for adding event listeners unobtrusively is to do it once the document has loaded. My point is that the user may well be able to interact with the document before it has fully loaded.

Comment: @Tim Down: I can't see the "significant downside" then. What would the user be able to interact with (or to do anything in general) if the page isn't fully loaded yet?

Comment: Sections of the page that have already loaded. The browser doesn't wait for the whole DOM to download before starting to render it. Try it: create a page on your server that sends some HTML, flushes the response and then waits for a while before serving the remainder of the page.

Comment: Here's a relatively old but interesting article on the subject: http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/the-window-onload-problem-still

Comment: @Tim Down: Well I'm aware of that article (it really is interesting). But still, writting unobtrusive code is a good thing. Assigning `inline javascript` can also cause a lot of trouble. What if a user clicks on an element with an inline handler, but the according javascript isn't loaded yet, boom error. So I'd prefer to have no reaction instead of an error here. And the maintainabilty is just so big, instead of checking for errors in two places (`html + js`) is just bad karma to me.

Comment: The you put the relevant JavaScript somewhere in the page before the element with the inline handler. Inside `<head>` would do. Bosh, no error. Really, I'm not trying to say you should always use event handler attributes, particularly for larger projects, and in fact I only use them myself in a limited number of situations. I'm just trying to encourage thinking for oneself rather than jumping straight onto the bandwagon of unobtrusiveness and pointing out a way in which the "unobtrusive" approach works less well than the alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.

```
`var ID = $(this).attr("id");`
```

sometimes using this method with arrow function (`

```
$('div).click(()=>{
console.log($(this).attr("id"))
}
```

`)
)Could result in undefined output so instead better  using the keyword 'function'

Answer (score 0):

In the function context **"this"** its not referring to the select element, but to the page itself

- Change `var ID = $(this).attr("id");`
  to `var ID = $(obj).attr("id");`

If **obj** is already a jQuery Object, just remove the $() around it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read more about the [this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

You cannot expect "this" to select the "select" tag in this case.

What you want to do in this case is use `obj.id` to get the id of select tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

`onchange='showHideOther.call(this);'`

instead of

`onchange='showHideOther(this);'`

But then you also need to replace `obj` with `this` in the function.