# jQuery: Passing element ID as part of function

Tags: jquery, function

Hopefully I am wording this correctly...

I am trying to pass an element id as an option in a jquery function:

```
        $('.carousel').createcarousel({
        theid: $(this).attr('id'), // this is the part I am trying to get working
        delay: 150,
        fade:300,
        slide: 700,
        effect:'slide',                   
        orientation:'horizontal',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false     });
```

Within the function itself, the options are defined as `o`, so I can do something like:

```
alert(o.fade);
```

And it will display an alert showing "300". However, if I do:

```
alert(o.theid);
```

It says undefined. Why?

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at createcarousel(). Did you try `theid: $('.carousel').attr('id')` ?

Comment: The reason I am using a class and not an id is because I am trying to have more than one carousel per page, so I am trying to pass the element id depending on which `.carousel` was clicked

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341342/jquery-this-attrid-not-working

Comment: You don't need to pass the id then!

try this :

$(".carousel").click(function(event){
   alert(event.target.attr("id"));
});

This should work out

See my edit on my answer

Comment: So why don't you use `this` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` isn't your object in your contect. I guess your `.carousel` classes each have an I'd and you want to assign it to the theid argument. However, in the object you are creating the context (`this` argument) doesn't match to your jQuery element, it matches to your function, where you create the caruses. So the jQUery object you are creating, wrappes an empty HTML element and has no id. Therefor it is set as undefined.

I think this will acomplish what you are trying to do:

```
$('.carousel').each(function() {
    $(this).createcarousel({
            //theid: $(this).attr('id'),                 
            theid: this.id,  //thanks jtheman
            delay: 150,
            fade:300,
            slide: 700,
            effect:'slide',                   
            orientation:'horizontal',
            loop: false,
            autoplay: false     });
});
```

This will iterate over all your carousel classes, set the `this` context correctly and apply the `createcarousel` function.

Comment: Why not just `theid: this.id` ?

Comment: Thank you. This passes the ID. Now I just need to get working on the rest of the code to enable it to work properly with more than one carousel per page.

Comment: Glad I could help. @jtheman once I started using jQuery, I use it for everything, without thinking if it could work without it. this.id is better of course.

Comment: @Stefan Yes I find myself in that situation many times! :D But now and then good old JS is even simpler and more efficient than jQuery...

Answer (score 0):

```
theid: $(this).attr('id')
```

In this context, $(this) refers to the carousel object which is not an html object.

Check out the jquery apply function. You can specify the context of a function call

http://api.jquery.com/Types/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DTypes%26redirect%3Dno#Context.2C_Call_and_Apply

scroll to "Context, Call and Apply"

Hope this helps out

---

Considering the comment you made on the other answer :

You don't need to pass the id then! try this :

```
$(".carousel").click(function(event){ 
    alert(event.target.attr("id")); 
});
```

event.target represents the html object which was clicked

This should work out