# Building html output with a input checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a string that will be place in a div pro grammatically. I am trying to call the `onclick` attribute of the input checkbox and having a little bit of trouble.  I am trying to pass a unique value id with each checkbox click.  The code below is what I'm using.  See below for the problem:

```
var count = 1;
$.each(JSON.parse(data.d), function (k, v) {
    var searchName = v.searchName;
    resultString += "<div class='row form-group'>";
    resultString += "<div class='col-sm-1 right-content'><input type='checkbox' onclick = 'authorCheckboxclick(this)' id='" + searchName + "'></div>";
    resultString += "<div class='col-sm-11'>";
    resultString += "<span>";
    //resultString +=  v.text   
    resultString += count + ". " + v.text
    resultString += "</span>";
    resultString += "<br />";
    resultString += "<span>";
    //resultString += "Consectetur adipisicing, Consequatur, 2015.";
    resultString += "</span>";
    resultString += "</div>";
    resultString += "</div>";
    //resultString += "<br><br>";
    count++;
});
```

In the `authorCheckboxclick` function if I put `var answerid = $(this).attr('id');` I get undefined.

```
function authorCheckboxclick(elem) {
    var answerid = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(answerid);  //I get undefined
    var answerid = $(this).attr(elem.id);
    alert(answerid); //I get undefined
    var answerid = $(this).attr(elem.id);
    alert(answerid); //I get undefined
    var searchTerm = elem.id;
    alert(searchTerm); //I get proper value
    searchTerm = searchTerm.substring(0, 3);
    alert(searchTerm); //I get proper value
    var answerid = $(this).attr(elem.id);
    alert(answerid); //I get undefined


    var search = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
    var array = jQuery.grep(dataMembers, function (value) {
        return value.toUpperCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    });
```

Is there a reason my jQuery call is not working and my JavaScript is?  Is there a best practice to send the id value to a junction?  Am I mixing Apples with Orange?  Which method show be faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery $(this).attr("id") not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341342/jquery-this-attrid-not-working)

Comment: Thanks-that works-- But is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate solution to your problem is that you're using the `this` keyword in your function. As you are calling the function from an `on*` attribute the scope of the function will be the `window`, not the element that raised the event. To fix this, simply use the element you provide in the parameter, ie. `$(elem)` instead of `$(this)`.

A better solution entirely would be to use an unobtrusive delegated event handler which can utilise the `this` keyword as you're attempting to. It also has the benefits of leaving cleaner HTML code and being a better separation of concerns. Try this:

```js
var count = 1;
$.each(JSON.parse(data.d), function(k, v) {
  var searchName = v.searchName;
  resultString += '<div class="row form-group">' +
    '<div class="col-sm-1 right-content"><input type="checkbox" id="' + searchName + '"></div>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-11">' +
        '<span>' + count + ". " + v.text + '</span><br />' +
        '<span></span>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>';
  count++;
});

$(document).on('change', '.row :checkbox', function() {
  var answerid = this.id;
  var search = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
  var array = jQuery.grep(dataMembers, function(value) {
    return value.toUpperCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks- I'll work it into my code.  Correct me if I'm wrong but this will be called for every checkbox in my entire application (Single page app) .  How can I determine which popup div it's coming from?  I use a lot of checkboxes within the app that call different functions

Comment: In that case you just need to make the `.row :checkbox` selector specific to the require page, ie `#profilePage .row :checkbox`

Comment: Should I preface my ID's so I know that they come from a special location?  Like  id= "publication"_+ ID value and id= "author" + ID Value

Comment: hate to be a pest but could #profilePage  be #profileDIV? and still work

Comment: You could do that - although I'd suggest using a common class over an `id`

Comment: Yes - it can be literally any valid selector, that was just an example